# conditional statement to show pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, pagination

I'm using pagination in my website using wordpress, to navigate between posts from the same category.
here is my code :

```
<div class="article_single_prev_next">
<div class="article_prev"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Article Précédent', TRUE); ?>
</div>
<div class="article_next"><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Article Suivant', TRUE);?>
</div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly.

But what I am trying to do is to add a if statement, to show the div "article_single_prev_next", only if there are next of previous pages inside the category.

I tried using this code without success:

```
<?php if (show_posts_nav('%link')) : ?>
<div class="article_single_prev_next">
<div class="article_prev"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Article Précédent', TRUE); ?>
</div>
<div class="article_next"><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Article Suivant', TRUE);?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you can use  [**get_adjacent_post**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post),which gives you the next post data it takes three parameters: `$in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, and $previous`.

```
if(get_adjacent_post(true, '', false)){
/* do what you want  */
}
```

Or if you are using [**wp loop**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts) you can check it by

```
global $wp_query;
if($wp_query->current_post + 1 < $wp_query->post_count){
/* do what you want  */
}
```

[**For more...**](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/conditional_and_custom_nextprevious_post_links_in_wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, I've found another solution, works fine :

```
<?php
$next_post_link = get_next_post_link( '%link', 'Article Précédent', TRUE );
$previous_post_link = get_previous_post_link( '%link', 'Article Suivant', TRUE );
if ( $next_post_link || $previous_post_link ) : ?>
    <div class="article_single_prev_next">
        <div class="article_prev">
            <?php echo $next_post_link; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="article_next">
            <?php echo $previous_post_link; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```